# Is assigning a function to window.onerror preferable to window.addEventListener('error', callback)?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Assigning a function to `window.onerror` seems like a pretty straightforward way to start handling errors in the code on a page. However, it's important to make sure you're not overwriting a pre-existing error handler, so it's usual practice to maintain a reference to the previous value and call it as part of your new function. As an example:

```
var old_onerror = window.onerror;
window.onerror = function() {
    // do something
    if (old_onerror) {
        old_onerror();
    }
};
```

Most documentation/blog posts/etc I can find online recommends doing something like this. Why don't they recommend adding an event handler for the `'error'` event instead? That allows multiple functions to be called when one of those events is triggered, and doesn't require awkwardly maintaining references to other error handlers.

```
window.addEventListener('error', function() {/* do something */});
```

Edit: I considered following [the standard advice on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick), but the `error` event on `window` seems to be a fairly special case (see, for example, JQuery's [explicit lack of support for it](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (search on that page for "onerror")). I'm specifically seeking insight on why `onerror` seems to be a special case.

Comment: Yeah, just use event listeners. Event handlers are only useful for ancient browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener vs onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: @AndrewL I considered following the standard advice on this subject, but the `error` event on `window` seems to be a fairly special case (see, for example, JQuery's [explicit lack of support for it](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (search on that page for "onerror")).

Comment: Can you please post some links to sites using the `old_onerror` technique?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For historical reasons these `window.onerror` is a bit of a special case. Most of these are defunct now, I think you have to back to IE8 to find a browser that needed them. A decade or so ago IE6 was king and it didn't have support for `addEventListener` at all, and many events were only supported by some browsers or had different names. Web development used to be wildly inconsistent and it's not unusual to find old methods like `window.onerror`.

For backwards compatability reasons `window.onerror` is a bit weird in that the two ways of subscribing to the event take different arguments.

So the legacy `onerror` includes error details as parameters:

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, line, col, error) {
    ...

    return true; // This will prevent further event propagation
};
```

This is still there so that old JS that's already out there doesn't break - browser designers want 10 year old websites to still basically work in their latest versions.

While the (now best practice) event listener has them as properties on the event:

```
window.addEventListener('error', e => {

    // Get the error properties from the error event object
    const { message, filename, lineno, colno, error } = e; 
});
```

The latter is far better, as you don't need to get any previous listeners, and no subsequent listeners (say from browser extensions) will accidentally break yours. Also you can remove your listener if you're building something like an SPA where you stay on one page with one `window` context.

So, to answer the question:

> Most documentation/blog posts/etc I can find online recommends doing something like this. Why don't they recommend adding an event handler for the 'error' event instead?

Because they're outdated. Keeping documentation up to date is hard and JS moves fast. The
`window.onerror` pattern you describe is still an acceptable compromise in some corporate environments where extremely outdated versions of IE need to be supported. For the vast majority of the web the `addEventListener` method is much better.

> see, for example, JQuery's explicit lack of support for it (search on that page for "onerror"

jQuery is *old*. There are some decisions that were made in 2006-2008 or so that it's now stuck with forever, and some assumptions that `.on` makes about events is one of those. jQuery's `.on` was great in 2006 because we didn't have to worry about different browsers' event implementations - it could hide all of them behind a common interface. Everything now uses `addEventListener` so you don't need it (and it's a lot more powerful than `.on`).

Comment: @07mm8 cheers, corrected in the proper event handler

Comment: What's the best way to prevent even propagation if using the more modern `window.addEventListener('error')`? Should we `return true` as with `window.onerror` or should we `event.preventDefault()` as with other regular events?

Comment: @cprcrack `event.preventDefault()` just stops the default handling (which is to do nothing but log it in the console). To stop it propagating use `event.stopPropagation()`. `window.onerror` still works for backwards compatibility but you shouldn't use it in new code (they will deprecate it eventually)

Comment: so `return true` inside the `window.addEventListener('error')` callback does nothing regarding preventing default handling or stopping propagation?

Comment: @cprcrack yes, `addEventListener` ignores whatever the callback returns.